# Can I expand/collapse content of JQuery ui Accordion by click another elements too?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

By default, there are headers of contents to control expand/collapse.But in my situation,I could expand/collapse the contents by another elements ,too. For example:

the basic structure of jquery ui accodion code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
......
</div>
```

and now. I have another elements,just like :

```
<ul id="another elements can expand/collapse too">
    <li><a href="">  expand/collapse contents of section1 of id=accordion too</a></li>
........
</ul>
```

thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.activate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#method-activate) with false passed in to collapse all elements programmatically.  Since you only ever have one element open at a time, this will work to collapse whatever element is open showing that link.  This will only work if you have `collapsible` set to `true`.

You can pass in what other element you want to expand to expand that element on click.

Answer (score 10):

After update of JQuery UI there is no "active" method on accordion. So, to collapse all accordions use:

```
$('.accordion').accordion('option', {active: false});
```

Comment: Can also collapse a single pane with:   $('.accordion').accordion('option,{active:false},idx);    -- where 'idx' is your pane number, zero-based.

Answer (score 9):

Collapse accordion tab:

```
$('.accordion').accordion('activate', false );
```

Expand first accordion tab:

```
$('.accordion').each(function (idx, item) {
    if ($(item).accordion("option", "active") === false) {
        $(item).accordion('activate', 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me from fiddling around, and I greatly appreciate your solution.

Comment: This tip worked for me. +1. I just had to change it to this: [`$('.accordion').accordion('option', 'active', false);` for jQuery UI `1.11`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I to had trouble getting the Accordions to collapse/expand after they were initially loaded.  To get around this I used:

```
$('#accordionId h3').click();
```

...which mimics clicking the header area and will force toggle the activation classes.

Felt like a hack, but it's what worked, Best.

Comment: According to [this user's "comment"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24591516/456814): "*`activate` method has been deprecated since jquery ui 1.9 and removed from 1.10+. More information on it and new syntax can be found at [jQuery UI 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-activate-method)*" That's according to that user though, I haven't taken the time to look into the issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap:

```
    //To Expand
    var elem  = $(this).find('.accordionElement');
    elem.addClass("in");
    elem.attr("style","");
    elem.attr("aria-expanded",true);
```

then you could collapse using:

```
    var elem  = $(this).find('.accordionElement');
    elem.removeClass("in");
    elem.attr("style","height: 0px;");
    elem.attr("aria-expanded",false);
```