# jQuery Accordion collapse on click link inside pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I've created an accordion on my page and I would like to be able to have some hyperlinked text within each pane that has expanded.

When you click the link 'Reduce text', it will need to collapse the accordion.

How can this be done by editing the existing code I have used?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        navigation: true,
        header: ".menuitem"
     });

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');
    if (anchor.length > 0){
        anchor.click();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3 class="menuitem">Item 1</h3>
<div>
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
<a href="#">Reduce text</a>
</div>

<h3 class="menuitem">Item 1</h3>
<div>
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
<a href="#">Reduce text</a>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
<div>
<h3 class="menuitem">Item 1</h3>
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
<a href="#">Reduce text</a>
</div></div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EA22W/

Hope I've explained well and the question makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Where is reduce text? And what happens when you click the anchor now?

Comment: I just edited the HTML, the Reduce text link is in there where it should be (it does nothing at the moment). I just need that link to collapse the accordion pane when clicked.

Comment: are you able to set up a minimal example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Here are some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681320/can-i-expand-collapse-content-of-jquery-ui-accordion-by-click-another-elements-t

It basically comes down to setting the accordion active parameter to false on the click of your reduce text link.

Comment: Hi @Jai here's the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EA22W/

Comment: Hi @berentrom, the active parameter is already set to active. What code to add the functionality to the actual 'reduce text' link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an on click event on the anchor element that closes its corresponding accordion item:

```
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    navigation: true,
    header: ".menuitem"
 });

var hash = window.location.hash;
var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');
if (anchor.length > 0){
    anchor.click();
}

//$("#accordion").on('click', '.ui-accordion-content a', function(){
$("#accordion").on('click', '.ui-accordion-content .reduce', function(){ //edit
    $(this).parent().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Comment: Hi @Andrei Cristian Prodan, thanks for that. Seems to work. I've added some other hyperlinks as content within the panes and when I click on them it conflicts with your code slightly. Is there a way to make this only function on links with the class "reduce"?

Comment: yes, just replace add class reduce to a in on event at second param like this: .on('click', '.ui-accordion-content a.reduce', function() ....

Comment: or eventually just leave it as .reduce instead of a.reduce because maybe in the future you want to turn that anchor into a div or other element

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code which can help you.

**Code**

```
function accordianReduce(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        navigation: true,
        header: ".menuitem"
     });  
}
accordianReduce()
$('.reduce').on('click', function(){
    accordianReduce() 
})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EA22W/1/)