# Linking to, and expanding, id within jQuery UI accordion loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a while loop set up, together with a jQuery UI accordion, where I now need to be able to link to a specific div id within the loop, and have that expanded automatically.

Having the id linked and jumped to is not a problem, but the expanding part troubles me; I've tried a few examples from other threads here, that sadly haven't done much.

this is my current jQuery UI accordion script:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(ui.newHeader.offset())) {
        $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: ui.newHeader.offset().top - 100 }, 'slow');
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestions as to what might be done? I can obviously provide more parts of the setup if needed.
The current setup can bee seen in action here: http://kar.co.com/jobs

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or what you're asking here.  You say you want to expand something... is that the containing accordion's div? or something else?  But then your code scrolls the body - where's the code that attempts to expand the accordion and on what trigger?

Comment: As of now, the each header expands when clicked, and scrolls the header to the top of the page (-100px). What I'm looking for is a way to expand the header when a specific div id is "activated". I.e. kar.co.com/#99066 which currently is the first header in the accordion loop.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active slightly out of date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681320/can-i-expand-collapse-content-of-jquery-ui-accordion-by-click-another-elements-t